# Emacs interactive regex replacement

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

Suppose You have some text with words like these inside:

```
"foo" ... "bar" ... "file" ... "emacs"
```

and all you want to do is to replace " with ' '. I know it can be done only asking for the following replacement:

```
" -> ''
```

but suppose you would like to do it interactively and with regex, for more complicated case, how can it be done?

I explain myself better: I wish I could have a command, or a series of them, to work in this way:

- Write a regex like `"\\(.*?\\)"` and see the results interactively (i.e. currently-visible matches are highlighted as you edit the regexp, and the highlighting is always updated as you make changes).
- Once happy with the regexp, specify a replacement such as `' '\1' '`
- Interactively replace all matches

Comment: what do you mean "recursively"?

Comment: event_jr: I updated the question based on Luigi's answer, and rephrased that part in the process, as it did not appear to be relevant.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally I've found out!!!!!
These are the steps to follow:

- `M-x isearch-forward-regexp`
- Insert your regex interactively. If you make a mistake you can use DEL or M-e and navigate through your regex to correct it.
- Then after you've found what you want immediately press M-% and the replacement you like and start replacing.

So you can search and replace with regex in a total interactive and incremental fashion.

Comment: Good find. On my installation `isearch-forward-regexp` is bound to `C-M-s`.

Comment: `M-x isearch-describe-bindings` (or `C-s C-h C-h b`) is well worth reading.

Comment: thank you for this. `isearch-describe-bindings` is also very helpful, though I wish I had some intuition about how I could have discovered that within Emacs. I continually find myself getting lost within Emacs's extensive documentation.

Answer (score 8):

- Run `M-x isearch-forward-regexp` or `C-M-s`.
- As you start typing a regex the first occurrence will be instantly highlighted. Attempting to move back through the regex using the cursor will cancel the search, so if you make a mistake you should use `M-e` to allow editing, make the change, then hit enter to continue the search.
- When you're happy with the regex, press `M-%`, type a replacement string (or use the up key to access previously used replacement strings), then press `RET` to start interactive replacement.
- For each occurrence, press `y` to replace once, `n` to skip, `!` to replace all, `RET` to exit, or `?` to see further options.
- To repeat your last regexp search enter `C-M-s` then `C-s`.

Full details are in the [manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Search.html).

Comment: I really just wanted to add some detail to [Luigi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11137064/201665), but since my edit was declined I'm posting it as a separate answer.

Comment: May the force be with you. With love,

Answer (score 7):

Does the command `query-replace-regexp` satisfy your requirements ? On most installations of Emacs it will be bound to `C-M-%`.

Since that doesn't satisfy OP's requirements, suggest looking also at `re-builder`.  This function is not documented in the Emacs manual, or help system, it is just about documented in the [Emacs Lisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html).

Comment: query-replace-regexp it's not interactive, or better incremental. I'd like to have an incremental way to look at what it's matched

Comment: It didn't work so for me, it's neither interactive nor incremental. Do you have any idea why? I've downloaded emacs through apt-get. By the way I've posted the solution that works fine in my case.

Comment: (sorry, I'd just deleted my first comment while you were adding your reply). I hadn't understood that you wanted incremental match highlighting *while you were building the regexp*, which is why I was confused. I understand what you were after now.